# Visual Studio: Archive the contents of a text file once a month

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, nlog, error-logging, archiving

Working with Visual Studio 2013 ASP .NET MVC 5, I have this .txt file in which I log the exceptions that are caught in my web application (using NLog). Every month, I want to archive that file into a different folder in my project. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: did you happen to follow any specific documentation or did you just use "common sense"? Meaning, you know how to develop .net mvc apps and just followed the nlog docs? Also, are you happy with the combo of nlog & mvc5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" internalLogFile="c:/logs/nlog_ex.txt" internalLogLevel="Debug">

  <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="exceptions"
            encoding="utf-8"
            lineEnding="Default"
            layout="${longdate} - ${message}"
            archiveFileName="c:/logs/${date:format=yyyy-MM}/exceptions.txt"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveEvery="Month"
            fileName="c:/logs/exceptions.txt"
            deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"
            enableFileDelete="true"
            createDirs="true"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            autoFlush="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="exceptions" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I used this [domcumentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options).